# The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.UWP.2015". in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp

Tried getting the library build by using release mode setting in configuration manager as Any CPU
I am getting the following error

> "The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is
>   not supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.UWP.2015, Version=3.30.1""

I am using the following references in the library:
1. SQLite for Universal Windows Platform
2. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjections
3. SQLite.Net-PCL
4. NewtonSoft.Json

Comment: I guess you need to chose x86 or x64.

Comment: Yeah, I need to chose one of the configuration. But I want to produce the .dll which supports any cnfiguration. I am getting this error because I am using SQLite for Universal Windows Platform. Can you suggest me a way to build the library for any configuration keeping the library ??

Comment: That's a contradiction. You either chose one platform or you start looking for another library. Those are your options.

Comment: Please attach configuration manager screen shot

Comment: I am getting the error in Errors tab, during the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite.dll file which is present in SQLite.UWP.2015 folder is specific to architecture. So, "Any CPU" doesn't work with this dll. In another way, you can build your project in the "Release" mode setting the architecture as x64/x84...